How to request a huge amount of select CJK characters from Google Fonts API?
I'm trying to figure out how to subset a Japanese font by simply using a Google Fonts API request. There seem to be two options: subset= and text=. However, the former requires a set name which seems to be the name of a Unicode block, and unfortunately there's no Unicode block that only includes jōyō kanji, which scatter all over the CJK Unified Ideographs block. If I used text=, I would have to include a monstrous string in the request, something like this:
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100..900&display=swap&text=亜哀挨愛曖悪握圧扱宛嵐安案暗以衣位囲医依委' rel='stylesheet'>

(clipped because this website thought I was spamming)
Is there a less unwieldy way?
